# Wordpress special characters and the_content

Tags: php, wordpress, special-characters

I'm trying to solve a really strange bug on a website I've developed.

In specific tags of the markup the web font is not rendering special characters like "éáçã".
The font allows such characters. You can even see parts of the page with such characters.

One strange behavior is that if you type the character again with the developer tools the character gets displayed correctly.

Hope someone can help me on this one.

Best
Peter

Comment: Please provide an example of the page content. Are the characters entered into the_content in UTF-8, as HTML entities, or some other way? Also, a specific place on at least one of those pages that is not displaying properly? I see many accented and otherwise non-ASCII glyphs on those pages. Which one is not properly displaying?

Comment: Continuing @JonathanEunice suggestions, check if database connection has UTF-8 as charset.

Comment: @JonathanEunice

All content is being inserted directly on the wysiwyg editor. All characters are UTF-8. If you check the page source (view-source:http://www.thebrandshakers.com/quem-somos/) you will see that everything is fine. 

By visiting the links I provided you can see that some of the non-ASCII glyphs are not being rendered with the correct font. Also try using a browser other than Chrome, specially on MAC. Firefox and Safari show the bug. Chrome Canary renders all ok.

Comment: @FabianoAraujo

Table collation are in utf8_general_ci. But you can check the screenshot here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1prj3h6r2glr9oi/Screen%20Shot%202014-10-23%20at%2021.21.09.png?dl=0

Comment: Any guess on this one?

Comment: Still can't find a way to solve this. I've used other fonts from google and no luck. All content seem ok on database and Wordpress WYSIWYG.

To explain better here is a printscreen https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1923549/screenshot-tbs-characters.png.

By editing the text on developer tools in Chrome I can type the character again and it renders ok.

Comment: Mean while I copy pasted the content directly into Windows Notepad ++ (I work on mac - Coda) and the app says or assumes an encoding of UCS-2 Little ENDIAN. Tried to convert to UTF-8 Without BOM but I would either loose the characters or it would stay the same once I copied again to Wordpress.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1923549/screenshot-tbs-characters-2.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so turns out the simplest way is to just confirm to deleted the text with bugs, save the post/page and write all again.